# graalvm In win10 64 bit Used in Windows 10 64-bit environment, error reported

Tags: graalvm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ462.png)
win10 64 Path entry 'C:\Program Files\graalvm-ce-java17-22.3.1\lib\dt.jar' does not map to a real path

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)